# A problem with getting/printing answers in a C# calculator

Tags: c#, error-handling, calculator

I'm trying to make simple projects for learning C# and have tried to make a simple console calculator. I have only found this current error when getting to the getting/printing the answer bit when test-running my program, so I have no idea if there are any other errors/things that will or may not work or run properly/as intended. So if there are any of those, please let me know and if you want to you can fix them yourself. It only recognized the error when it reached that specific line of code, and otherwise will run the program until it reaches the error.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string num1;
            string num2;
            string condition;
            string answer;
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("For division, use /. For multiplication, use *.\n");
            
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: "); // gets first number to add in problem
                num1 = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a condition: "); // gets condition to add in problem
                condition = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number: "); // gets second number to add in problem
                num2 = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Calculating..");
                // converting strings to int and working out answer
                Convert.ToInt32(num1);
                Convert.ToInt32(num2);
                // error is from here on (not sure if the Convert.ToInt32() code above causes errors)
                answer = num1 + condition + num2;
                Convert.ToInt32(answer);
                Console.WriteLine(answer);
                // sets values to null after getting & printing answer (probably unnessessary)
                answer = null;
                num1 = null;
                num2 = null;
                condition = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Misha Zaslavsky you too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive input (condition) as a string

cant do this : answer = num1 + condition + num2 because those variables are
string

you have to check that with switch , for example :

```
            int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, answer = 0;
            string condition;
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("For division, use /. For multiplication, use *.\n");

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: "); // gets first number to add in problem
                num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a condition: "); // gets condition to add in problem
                condition = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number: "); // gets second number to add in problem
                num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Calculating..");
                // converting strings to int and working out answer
                Convert.ToInt32(num1);
                Convert.ToInt32(num2);
                // error is from here on (not sure if the Convert.ToInt32() code above causes errors)
                switch (condition)
                {
                    case "/":
                        answer = num1 / num2;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        answer = num1 * num2;
                        break;
                    case "+":
                        answer = num1 + num2;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        answer = num1 - num2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("error : unknown operator");
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(answer);
                // sets values to null after getting & printing answer (probably unnessessary)
            }
```

Comment: i changed num1 and .. from string to int , and at the reading from input converted them to int by int.Parse

Answer (score 1):

When facing problems like this one - the routine is *too complex* to be tested:

> if there are any other errors/things that will or may not work"

split routine into smaller ones: start *extracting methods*.

```
// Get integer value from user
public static int ReadInteger(string title) {
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
      return result;

    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a valid integer value, please, try again.");
  }
}

// Get character operator ('+', '-' etc.) from user
public static char ReadOperator(string title, string operators) {
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

    if (input.Length == 1 && operators.Contains(input[0]))
      return input[0];  

    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a valid operator, please, try again.");
  }
}
```

Now we are ready to implement `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  while (true) {
    int num1 = ReadInteger("Enter a number: ");
    char op = ReadOperator("Enter a condition: ", "+-*/");
    int num2 = ReadInteger("Enter your second number: ");

    //TODO: I've skipped error handling (zero division, overflow)
    int answer = 
      op == '+' ? num1 + num2 :
      op == '-' ? num1 - num2 : 
      op == '*' ? num1 * num2 :
      op == '/' ? num1 / num2 : 0;

    Console.WriteLine($"{num1} {op} {num2} = {answer}");
 
    //TODO: it's a right place here to ask user if (s)he wants to continue
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this line because all the variables are `strings` and not the real values (e.g: `num1 & num2` should `ints/doubles`... and condition should be a real operator).

```
answer = num1 + condition + num2;
```

Also, you can't do it because let's assume the user inputs the multiplication sign, and then the string of `"*"` is not equal to the sign of `*`.

Instead, you can do some `switch-case` statements to check the value of the `condition` variable. Also, you need to make sure `num1 & num2` are numbers (you can parse/try-parse them to a number (`int/double`...)). You will also have to parse them to another variables as they are strings.

```
switch (condition)
{
    case '*':
        answer = numX * numY;
        break;
    case "/":
       // Validate that numY is not 0 to avoid [DivideByZeroException][1]
       answer = numX / numY;
       break;
    ...
}
```

Note, it is just one way to do it and I just gave you a small example that might help you to continue.

I would also offer you to make a default case (in case that the input of the user is not something you expect, in this case, you may ask him again to write an input because the current input is invalid).